# SARG-able date conversion

Tags: sql-server, query-performance

I just came across some SQL Server queries that have the following non-SARG-able predicate in their WHERE clauses:

`AND ((CONVERT(DATETIME, SWITCHOFFSET(T.TimeStamp, DATEPART(TZOFFSET, T.TimeStamp AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time'))) >= @from_date)`

I'm thinking that it can be rearranged so that it is SARG-able. I'm also thinking that it's nuanced and that I could use some advice.

Is it as simple as converting @from_date to UTC?

Comment: Directly - no. You must retrieve the value timezone. So you must apply the function which extracts the timezone from the value. This makes your query non-SARGable. Try to create an index by used expression - maybe the server will use it (the expression in the index and those in the query must be the same literally). If server won't use this index then try to create generated column which stores the datatime value converted to UTC and use it in your query instead of the expression.

Comment: In what timezone is `T.Timestamp` stored? Seems like you are double adjusting but I'm not following the logic entirely

Comment: @Akina FWIW, you can't create an index on an expression in SQL Server.

Comment: @J.D. Maybe, I don't remember. if so then index by generated column will help.

Answer (score 2):

If `T.Timestamp` is stored as a `datetime` in UTC, then yes, all you need to do is convert `@from_date` into UTC, then converting it to `datetime`.

```sql
AND T.TimeStamp >= CAST(@from_date AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS datetime)
```

However, the exact logic desired is unclear. Your current code appears to be double-adjusting the time zone, by using both `AT TIME ZONE` and `SWITCHOFFSET`

Comment: I'll do some more looking into the data on this query. Just looking in the code repository, I was thinking that the data is in UTC. Not a good thing to presume.